# calc_switch_cases() in IDApython, can't iterate over results

Tags: ida, idapython

i'm actually quite new to IDApython programing and i'm trying to get, for a "switch-case" jump table, the list of basic blocks for a given value of the case.

While experimenting, i was trying to access the switch-case table using the following code as following the official documentation.

```
import idautils
import idaapi
import idc

myfunc=0
jump_table = dict()
switch_map = {}

for func in idautils.Functions():
    if 'Myfunction_name' == idc.GetFunctionName(func):
        print 'function found'
        myfunc = func
        break

for (startea, endea) in Chunks(myfunc):
    for head in Heads(startea, endea):
        switch_info = idaapi.get_switch_info_ex(head)
        if switch_info != None:
            num_cases = switch_info.get_jtable_size()
            if num_cases == 148:
                print 'good jump table found'
                results = idaapi.calc_switch_cases(head, switch_info)
                for idx in xrange(results.cases.size()):
                    cur_case = results.cases[idx]
                    """
         --->       #can't use the following

           -->      for cidx in xrange(len(cur_case)):
           -->          print "case: %d" % cur_case[cidx]
                    """
                    print "  goto 0x%x" % results.targets[idx]
                #for cidx in xrange(cur_case.size()):
                print cur_case
                print "  goto 0x%x" % results.targets[idx]
            else:
                continue
        else:
            continue
```

Unfortunately, i am not able to access correctly the cases values, as shown by the arrows in the code. Indeed, the "cur_case" object is a PySwigObject, which is not iterable.

Any idea on how to get that code to work? (notes : i'm using IDA 64 bits)

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, my bad... I was actually using IDA 6.8, and the API for this version does not create iterable Objects.

Using IDA 7 solved the problem.